# How to parse the output of a stored procedure in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure `lookahead_monitor_SP` and added it to my entity framework and I can call the SP from my C# code  and it returns the correct count of rows however I don't understand how to parse the data from it?  how to parse the data?

Stored procedure:-

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`wciadmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `lookahead_monitor_SP`()
BEGIN
select lrcl.lookahead_run_id,lr.ec_job_link,lr.submitted_by,lr.submission_time,lr.lookahead_run_status,cl.change_list from lookahead_run lr
        join lookahead_run_change_list lrcl on lr.lookahead_run_id=lrcl.lookahead_run_id
        join change_lists cl on cl.change_list_id=lrcl.change_list_id
        order by lr.lookahead_run_id DESC;
END
```

EF change:--

```
   public virtual ObjectResult<lookahead_monitor_SP_Result> lookahead_monitor_SP()
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<lookahead_monitor_SP_Result>("lookahead_monitor_SP");
    }
```

CODE:-

[image]

UPDATE:

namespace Dashboard.EntityFramework
{
    using System;

```
public partial class lookahead_monitor_SP_Result
{

}
```

}

Complete type

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var context = new YourDBContext())
{
    var rez = context.lookahead_monitor_SP();

    foreach (lookahead_monitor_SP_Result lmSPr in rez)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(lmSPr.Submission_time);
    }
}
```

For details check [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: I followed the instructions @`http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx` and set up a `complex type` as the columns are from different tables but somehow the autogenerated class for `lookahead_monitor_SP_result` is empty...even if I try to add fields to it once I rebuild it gets erased..what am missing?I updated the question with the same

Comment: not sure why it's built empty. I tried on y sample project and it worked jut fine. What confuses me is that you have Not supported in edm type. This is not good. If you are using mysql - this seems to be a bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046527/mysql-ef-6-stored-procedure-import-function-edm-type-not-supported. As a note, when you add properties manually, do you just type them in? In that case they will disappear on rebuild. Use "Add->scalar property" under right click on the complex type